SF Symbol replace animation size is off
I want to achieve this animation where the wifi symbol is slashed:

It's partly working, but the wifi bars are scaling and moving

I'm using this code:
Image(systemName: showSlash ? "wifi.slash" : "wifi")
    .font(.system(size: 22))
    .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
    .foregroundStyle(.black)
    .symbolRenderingMode(.hierarchical)
    .contentTransition(.symbolEffect(.replace))

It seems the wifi bars in the "wifi.slash" icon are smaller, but in the SF symbols app they appear the same size. What am I doing wrong?

Is this a new thing in iOS 18? The animation is different for me on iOS 17.4. That said, why do you have .padding(.top, showSlash ? 0 : 2)? That probably nudges the symbol a little.

Ah. I should have removed that in my code snippet. That was my hacky fix to offset this size difference.. Removed now

And yeah I think this is new in 18

The reason for the jumping is because the symbols have different dimensions:

neither are square
the "wifi" symbol (without the slash) is a wide rectangle
the "wifi.slash" symbol (with the slash) is taller, but still not quite square
with "wifi.slash", the base part of the symbol (the 3 radial lines) is not center-aligned vertically.

This is how the two symbols look when shown adjacent to each other with a red border around each, using (vertical) center alignment:

Although the base part of the symbol is not center-aligned in the version with the slash, it seems the two versions do align on the text baseline. So if you show the symbol in a ZStack and use a hidden copy of the version with a slash to provide the reference for alignment, the jumping can be avoided:
ZStack(alignment: .centerFirstTextBaseline) {
    Image(systemName: "wifi.slash")
        .hidden()
    Image(systemName: showSlash ? "wifi.slash" : "wifi")
        .contentTransition(.symbolEffect(.replace))
}
.font(.system(size: 22))
.frame(width: 24, height: 24)
.foregroundStyle(.black)
.symbolRenderingMode(.hierarchical)

I was testing on iOS 17, so I just commented out the .contentTransition to confirm that the jumping wasn't happening. I hope the transition works as expected when running with iOS 18.

Thanks works like charm, thanks! All are symbols aligned on the text baseline?

@Tieme Pleased to have been able to help, thanks for accepting the answer! I looked for documentation to see whether all symbols are aligned this way. The WWDC20 event notes say the text baseline is used as a flexible guide, sometimes symbols are lower or higher than the baseline: this is intended and it’s meant to optically balance the shape of the symbol with the text. So it probably works this way most of the time, but not always.
